# Getting different classpath behavior running SWT app from bash command line and in a script in OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt

I'm a bit of a newbie to SWT and rusty with Java and Eclipse in general.  I've been writing a simple app to recover the mindset (it's actually an arithmetic facts quiz program for my granddaughter).  I'm using SWT for cocoa/osx/x86_64 platform.  The goal is ultimately to package the app up into an OS X .app bundle.

Here's where I've fallen and can't get up:  It works OK when executed from inside the Eclipse IDE, and *also* works OK when executed standalone from an interactive bash shell using a java command line, but throws a NoClassDefFoundError exception when run from inside a shell script.  The script in question is about as simple as possible:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java \
       -d64 \ 
       -XstartOnFirstThread \
       -jar MathDrill.jar
```

The stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I've got everything slurped up into one jar file, with the jar containing swt.jar (which in turn contains the *.jnilib files for the platform) and a bunch of the binding framework jars (wow, that was painful--but I digress).  I've tried:

a) Creating the manifest through using Eclipse "export to runnable jar" file.

b) Creating the manifest through "export to jar" (which adds a "Rsrc-Main-Class" line to the manifest anyway, so I'm not sure what the real difference is).

c) Creating a runnable jar by extracting the enclosed jars to a a library directory and modifying the shell script to add a -classpath .:./libdir

The manifest in question is, after extracting META-INF from the generated jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ swing2swt.jar org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.1.v  
 20120521-2329.jar org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.2.200.v2012052
 3-1955.jar org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20120521-23
 29.jar org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.100.v20120523-1955.j
 ar org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.6.0.v20120521-2329.jar org.eclipse
 .equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v2011082
 3.jar swt.jar
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Class-Path: .
Created-By: 1.6.0_37-b06-434-10M3909 (Apple Inc.)
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.rutabaga.mathdrill.MathDrill
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Some questions:

1) The manifest shows up with the weirdo 80-column word wrap plus space after a "jar xf MathDrill.jar META-INF" command.  Is this normal?  It's certainly not like that in the ant tags that built it.

2) What's the difference between Class-Path and Rsrc-Class-Path in the manifest?

3) When I export to jar in Eclipse (instead of runnable jar) it generates a "jar-in-jar-loader.zip" file.  What is this?  How am I supposed to use it?

4) Is there a way to execute java directly from an OS X bundle without having some kind of script to launch it?  I've tried following the directions I found at http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/, and I've also tried using Platypus--same class loader exception in both cases.

5) Is there something weird that happens to the environment when executing java from a shell script?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure I've done something stupid but I'm kinda dead in the water for right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the shell script changes it's working directory to that containing the `.jar` file. If the shell script and the `.jar` file are in the same directory, you may just need to have the lines immediately prior to the `exec java`:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

otherwise, you may need to specify the path to the `.jar` file explicitly in the shell script using:

```
exec java \
   -d64 \ 
   -XstartOnFirstThread \
   -jar "$(dirname "$0")/MathDrill.jar"
```

Comment: Nope, fooling with the working directory didn't do it--same problem as before.  BTW, the script and the jar are indeed in the same directory.

Comment: huh, when things like this happen when running a shell script, I put a `set -x` at the start of the script, remove the exec, and put a `set` invocation to display all the variables in the script. If there's a dodgy default `CLASSPATH` variable, it tends to mess up directory-tree class access. Trap the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, in case. Trap the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, in case it's not actually the main class that's triggering the exception, but something missing in the invocation. Your jar manifest says look in `cwd` for the jars in `Rsrc-Class-Path`

Comment: Well, I knew it was gonna be stupid when I found it, and it was.  I had a non-newline whitespace after "-d64 \ ", which the shell must have interpreted as a completion of the command line.  So it never even saw the jar spec.  Thanks for your help--if I hadn't been monkeying around with the shell script, I would've never found the silly thing.